# Returned y-value larger than actual y-position [JS (no jQ) / DOM]

Tags: javascript, dom, position, positioning, offset

I calculate the y-position of the element el in one of the following two ways:

```
var elTop = 0;                    
do{
    el += el.offsetTop;
    }while(el = el.offsetParent); 
    window.scrollTo(0, elTop);
```

and

```
   var elTop = (el.getBoundingClientRect()).top;
   window.scrollTo(0, elTop);
```

in both cases elTop is too high and scrollTo jumps too far.

I tried this script online. When I downloaded the whole page with Firefox it suddenly worked. There were no differences online/offline in the visual apperance, or the structure.
Only the offsetHeight of the body changed and the offsetTop of the searched element.

How could these attributes change without any visual effect?

Comment: Could you provide entire html page code, with all elements and styles.

Answer (score 0):

To avoid mentioned problems, you should consider using getBoundingClientRect() + "page scroll" instead of calculating all element offsets.

```
var yPosition = element.getBoundingClientRect().top + window.pageYOffset;
```

http://jsbin.com/ukuRaXe/2/edit

Note, that this solution doesn't work in < IE9.

Comment: Thanks, but the returned y-value is the same as before. 

How can the calculated/returend y-value be larger than the actual y-position of the element?

Comment: Can you share whole page code? As for now it sounds absolutely unbelievable.